# Is there a theory of "functions with unspecified number of arguments"?

Tags: functions

In programming languages, it is often possible to define a function that takes a "list" of real numbers as an argument.

**Is there also in math a theory of functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments?** For example a function that takes an arbitrary number of natural numbers as a arguments, and calculates their product.

Comment: It would be more typical to say the domain is the set of finite subsets of the natural numbers, I would think.

Comment: @saulspatz $f(\{0,1\})=f(\{1,0\})$ doesn't model $f(0,1)\neq f(1,0)$. But ofcourse, it is not hard to take the union of all sets of tuples of any (finite or reasonably bounded by some ordinal) size.

Comment: I was referring to your example.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'arbitrary amount'.

Comment: @blueInk, what notation would we use for a function whose domain is the set of all tuples of natural numbers?

Comment: $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ ... kind of kidding. Like in the computer, you can write $f(x)$ and say that $x$ is a tuple, or even say which tuple depending on the case, and also the abuse of notation $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_n):=f((a_1,a_2,...,a_n))$. I am not completely sure, but I think in C++ a variadic function allows both the syntax $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ and $f(\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\})$. Is that right? In math braces $\{\}$ are more commonly used for sets, than for tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model a function with arbitrary arguments by defining a set of arbitrary tupples. Which can be done recursively 
$$ A^0 = \emptyset $$
$$ A^1 = A $$
$$ A^n = A \times A^{n-1} $$
$$ A^* = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A^n $$

Then you define functions $f : A^* \to B$ this will allow you to model an arbitrary aririty function.

Comment: Of course, this only lets you define functions with an arbitrary *finite* number of arguments. But I suspect that it answers OPs question -- nicely done.

Comment: For infinite arguments you have the function operate on sequences $f: A^\mathbb{N} \to B$

Comment: ...or at least for countably infinite arguments. :)